# Eigen: simple optimization with multiplication and addition

Tags: c++, eigen

I was reading eigen documentation and found a small discussion about optimization. The discussion is under the title "`A note about expression templates`" in this page of documentation  http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixArithmetic.html

It gives an example

```
VectorXf a(50), b(50), c(50), d(50);
...
a = 3*b + 4*c + 5*d;
```

and at the end it says

> Thus, you should not be afraid of using relatively large arithmetic expressions with Eigen: it only gives Eigen more opportunities for optimization.

I don't understand how it do the optimization and how it provides more opportunity for optimization? An explanation would be nice.

Comment: The explanation is on the page you link to, before the sentence you quote... If you're having trouble understanding part of the explanation, at least explain which part of it is unclear to you, if you want to avoid risking getting an answer here which is equally unclear to you.

Comment: It's a blessing and a curse, it can be also the source of some very strange bugs... see for example here: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLazyEvaluation.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the page you are quoting and the [Writing efficient matrix product expressions](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicWritingEfficientProductExpression.html) page, the point is, if you have a choice of :

**MethodOne**

```
VectorXf a(50), b(50), c(50), d(50);
...
a = 3*b + 4*c + 5*d;
```

**MethodTwo**

```
VectorXf a(50), b(50), c(50), d(50);
...
a = 3*b + 4*c;
a += 5*d;
```

you should prefer MethodOne.

Thus, allowing the software optimization to gain iterations through your vectors

> Eigen compiles it to just one for loop, so that the arrays are traversed only once.

and also, more room for optimization is available through the `.noalias()` call, and which simplifies the expression to single evaluations (if possible, limitations exist) :

> Use .noalias() to tell Eigen the result and right-hand-sides do not alias. Otherwise the product m2 * m3 is evaluated into a temporary.